# Why is this promise being rejected?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I encountered a bug recently that led me to experimenting with promises, and found something that I couldn't figure out.

I have tested this both in Node v11.9, as well as Google Chromes console.

This example shows what I'm talking about:

```js
  Promise.reject("I dont throw").catch(console.log)

  Promise.reject('I throw').catch().catch(e => console.log(e))
```

As you can see, the second catch is the one that's logging the error.

I had to include the second `catch()` block in order for this snippet to log the error, but the following example can be run in a browser which produces a rejected promise:

```
    Promise.reject("I dont throw").catch(console.log) 
    // -> Logs "I don't throw"


    Promise.reject('I throw').catch()
    // -> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:
```

So my question is:  Why is the error still thrown with an empty catch block?

I'm assuming it's because there's no callback, and internally there's some check that skips an undefined catch callback and continues on the chain to another catch block, or in this case, an unhandled rejection.

But if this is the case, why does VSCodes Typescript typings have `.catch()` listed as:

```
catch<TResult = never>(onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult | PromiseLike<TResult>) | undefined | null): Promise<T | TResult>;
```

Does this mean the typings are incorrect?

Comment: What exactly is the issue you're seeing in the typings? `onrejected?:` means that the parameter is optional

Comment: The issue that it still throws a rejected promise when onrejected is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `catch` requires a function pointer/deleget/lambda

```
Promise.reject("I dont throw").catch(console.log)
Promise.reject('I throw').catch().catch(e => console.log(e))
```

in the second promise you are catching the error thrown by the first catch of the promise.

```
Promise.reject('I throw')
   .catch() //This throws an error (Undefined, etc)
   .catch(e => console.log(e))  //this catches that error thrown
```

if you want to catch and ignore then

```
Promise.reject('I throw')
   .catch((error) => { /*Just Ignore*/ }) //Just Add an empty function
```

ref:

- [Promise.prototype.catch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I skimmed the important part at the top: "in fact, calling obj.catch(onRejected) internally calls obj.then(undefined, onRejected)" the first time I read through it.  That was exactly the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

> So my question is: Why is the error still thrown with an empty catch block?

Passing undefined into`.catch` don't actually handle the rejection.

The log of second example `unhandledpromiserejection`  just warmed you that you hadn't handle rejection properly.

The definition in TypeScript is fine. Why? Refer the [official ECMAScript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-promise.prototype.catch):

> When the catch method is called with argument onRejected, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let promise be the this value.
> 2. Return ? Invoke(promise, "then", « undefined, onRejected »).

Sine `.then` can be called like:

```
p.then(onResoled); // just handle resolution, here onRejected is undefined
```

Make argument `handler` in `.catch(handler)` optional doesn't violate anything.

Comment: So why do the official Typescript typings list the parameter for .catch as optional?